# Could prime factorization of n!+1 using the general number field sieve be said to take subfactorial time?

Tags: prime-numbers, factorization

I am interested in the prime factorization using the general number field sieve. This method is said to take subexponential time relative to the number of bits in a number. (Other algorithms are exponential.) I have two questions about this:

1. Could this operation be said to take subfactorial time?
2. Does this operation on average take greater than exponential time? If so, then it is between exponential and factorial.

Answer (score 2):

For a number $n$ that has $b=1+\log_2 n=O(\ln n)$ bits
NFS has complexity of the order
$$
\exp\left\{(c+o(1)) (\ln n)^{1/3} (\ln \ln n)^{2/3}\right\}
$$

which is subexponential when compared to the input size in bits. An exponential algorithm would have
complexity of the order
$$
\exp(c b)=\exp(c \ln n).
$$

If the unusual term factorial time means an algorithm takes time asymptotic to $\ln b!$ for the input size $b$ the answers to your questions are both yes.